# Editing PHP in Microsoft Visual Studio Express 2012

Tags: php, visual-studio-2012

Is there a way to install something in VS *Express* so I can edit PHP in VS Express Web and have the program color the text like in HTML and JS?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Visual Studio does not support PHP natively.  There are a couple different extensions that can add support:

- [VS.Php for Visual Studio](http://www.jcxsoftware.com/vs.php) (commercial with trial period)
- [PHP Tools for Visual Studio](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/6eb51f05-ef01-4513-ac83-4c5f50c95fb5) (commercial with trial period)

However, VS Express does not allow you install extensions, so I would recommend installing [Visual Studio Community Edition](https://www.visualstudio.com/community) so you can use extensions.

Microsoft has a couple other development tools which support PHP, so, you might try one of them:

- [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/)
- [Web Matrix](http://www.microsoft.com/web/webmatrix/)